# application.inputbox error after clicking OK with empty input

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I really searched hours and hours, but I can't find any solutions.

You should only enter numbers into the Inputbox and a msgbox should sppears when you just hit ok without any number or string...

The first part was easy, but I always get an error message by just hitting OK!

```
Public Sub test()
Dim vntReturn As Variant
vntReturn = Application.InputBox("Bitte Wert eingeben", "Eingabe", , , , , , 1)
If StrPtr(vntReturn) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Abbrechen gedrückt"
Else
    If vntReturn = False Then
        MsgBox "Nix eingegeben"
    Else
        MsgBox vntReturn
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you're declaring the Type for this InputBox to a number. So excel will automatically try to correct this. You can use an InputBox without a Type and program your own verification for checking if it's an integer or not.

Otherwise you can also add this before your code:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

And then set it to True after. Now when you hit ok you won't be prompted with the error, but the InputBox will not go away. You could add additional instructions to the InputBox to make it clear it needs a number.

Comment: While the first part of your answer actually would solve the problem I feel that you didn't fully explain why the error happens. When you use the `Application.InputBox` with a `Type` parameter 1 it works like a function. It tries to evaluate whatever is in the box. It thrown an error if it's not a number. So have a quick look at the code in my answer to better understand how to handle situation like that.

Comment: well, I've used now your code and that's exactly what I want. If I just click "ok" nothing happens, no error message etc. 
BUT now if I enter a letter no error message will appear and at least there should be a error message for strings....
How is that possible?

Comment: @Tommy which answer are you using then because you have accepted Alex'es but I think youre using the code from my answer actually hehe

Comment: Tommy I'd simply have it state on the InputBox that you won't allow strings. Sadly you can't always have the best of both worlds since it won't accept the input at all if it's a string too.

And @mehow we have nearly the same solutions, I posted earlier, with an explanation of why it was happening. I think it's a moot point, but I upvoted your post earlier if you're just doing it for the points.

Comment: @mehow Not accusing anything haha, just saying ;). And enjoying StackOverflow so far. It's a nice distraction and break from doing work.

Comment: @mehow: as Alex D just said: Your answers are similar ;-)

Answer (score 0):

@mehow: as Alex D just said: Your answers are similar ;-)
First I used the code of mehow, but now I just create a userform with only an "OK-button".

```
Private Sub Rechnen_Click()
Dim i As Integer            ' Variable deklarieren
Dim Sum As Integer
Dim counter As Variant
i = 0                       ' deklariert, löst beim Kompilieren keinen Fehler aus
Sum = 0                     ' nicht deklarierte Variable löst beim Kompilieren einen Fehler aus
counter = TextBox1.Value
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If Not IsNumeric(counter) Then
Exit Sub
Else
Unload Userform1
    On Error Resume Next
    Do Until i >= counter

    Zahl = InputBox("Pls enter a number:", i + 1 & ". Versuch")
    Sum = Sum + Zahl
    i = i + 1

    If Not IsNumeric(Zahl) Then
    MsgBox "calculation premature cancelled!"
    Exit Do
    End If

    Loop
    Ausgabe = MsgBox("Die Summe lautet: " & Sum, vbInformation, "Ergebnis")
    Question = MsgBox("is it enough?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "repeat")
        If Question = vbNo Then
        Userform1.Show
        Else
        Unload Userform1
        Exit Sub
        End If
End If
End Sub
```

and so the userform looks like:

[image]

Now the program works fine ;) Thank you guys!

Comment: while your question has changed since the first posting I am not going to comment on the answers you've got. Glad it's sorted